# How to autocomplete files under specific directory?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I created a command `memo` as follows:

```sh
memo() {
  vi $HOME/memo/$1
}
```

I want to apply bash-completion to my `memo` to open files that is already in `$HOME/memo` directory:

```sh
$ memo [TAB] # to show files in $HOME/memo
```

`$HOME/memo` contains directory, so listing the file under `memo` is not sufficient.
In other words, I want to apply what is used in `ls` command in `$HOME/memo` to `memo`:

```sh
$ ls [TAB]
foo.md bar/
```

I tried the below but it doesn't work for nested directories:

```sh
_memo() {
    local cur
    local files
    _get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur
    files=$(ls $MEMODIR)
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${files}" -- "${cur}") )
}
complete -F _memo memo
```

`MEMODIR=$HOME/memo`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```sh
_memo()
{
    local MEMO_DIR=$HOME/memo
    local cmd=$1 cur=$2 pre=$3
    local arr i file

    arr=( $( cd "$MEMO_DIR" && compgen -f -- "$cur" ) )
    COMPREPLY=()
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#arr[@]}; ++i)); do
        file=${arr[i]}
        if [[ -d $MEMO_DIR/$file ]]; then
            file=$file/
        fi
        COMPREPLY[i]=$file
    done
}
complete -F _memo -o nospace memo
```

---

[image: auto-complete]

Comment: Related to this topic but not an actual answer to the OPs question: I wanted an auto complete just like the OP but to only include dirs. I was trying to tweak this answer when I found that the `_cd()` function for bash autocomplete has a `$CDPATH` var that does exactly what I needed.