# Mac OS bash script argument - tab completion when its not the full file path

Tags: bash, macos

File path is

```
/Users/me/Document/project/tests/unittests1/testfile1.js
/Users/me/Document/project/tests/unittests2/testfile2.js
```

I need to run bash script from `project` directory. Bash script is in project directory.

The argument to the bash script needs to be `unittests/testfile.js` instead of the whole path `/Users/me/Document/project/tests/unittests/testfile.js`

Is there a way tab complete can work if I type just `unit` as argument and hit tab for tab completion?

Comment: yes, if you `cd` into tests before ;)

Comment: :) any other way without doing `cd` into tests?

Comment: if "Bash script is in project directory", then doesn't the argument to the bash script needs to be `tests/unittests/testfile.js` instead of `unittests/testfile.js` ?

Comment: the way the test framework is built right now its `unittests/testfile.js`

Comment: also, you can `export` enviroment variable like  `export ut=/Users/me/Document/project/tests/unittests/` and `echo $ut `

Comment: i don't think that TAB will search recursive through entire disk, but of course you could write a script for `find` which will satisfied with pattern *unit* as argument

Comment: You can customize completion, so you could probably configure it so that when the command is this particular script, it performs completion relative to the `tests` directory.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Olha Path resolution doesn't have anything to do with the location of the script (at least, by default). Relative paths are resolved based on the current working directory, which is  inherited from the working directory of the process that started it (i.e. your shell). If you `cd` to the script's directory before running it, that'll be the script's directory; otherwise, it won't. Reliably resolving paths relative to the location of the script is [actually rather difficult](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: The shell script needs to `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` if the PWD of the script is so important.

Comment: just answered a similar question yesterday. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979947/